# Default date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, default

how can I correct this query, I need to change a column to start if the value is null

alter table PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT modify date_start date default '01/01/2000 00:00:00'; ???

regards

Comment: You can set default for TIMESTAMP column but only current time and only in 5.6 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT MODIFY date_start DATE DEFAULT '2000-01-01';
```